# Evaluating the javascript from html response?

Tags: jquery, browser, javascript

var htmlResponse is the variable that contains complete html response i.e containing the javascript function and html content

Now i want to evaluate the javascript out of this response

i tried below jquery function but does not work and gives some weird error

```
  $.globalEval(htmlResponse);
```

I am not sure is there any standard javascript function where we can give complete html response and function
extracts the javascript out of it and evaluate it(so that it can be executed and can be put in current browser context)?

Comment: When you make the Ajax call, are you specifying an expected return content type of "html"?

Comment: Have You looked at jquerys [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function?

Comment: jQuery automatically evaluates script elements in html when it parses it... so just `$(htmlResponse)` or `$.parseHTML( htmlResponse, true )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$("#divSelector").html( htmlResponse ) does evaluate the javascript  automatically while appneding